# Reading an Amazon S3 log file

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

So I am having problems reading anything from a bucket

I know I am connecting fine as I am getting a listing of the bucket contents, I retrieve the key and I am trying to use it as such

```
foreach (var log in logs.Select(q => q.logFile).ToList())
        {
    var getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest().WithBucketName(bucketName).WithKey(log);
    var getObjectResponse = new GetObjectResponse();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(getObjectResponse.ResponseStream);
    String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I get back

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream

on

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(getObjectResponse.ResponseStream);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your `getObjectResponse` is setup incorrectly. You are simply creating a new `GetObjectResponse`. It is not hooked up to `getObjectRequest`.

Change

```
var getObjectResponse = new GetObjectResponse();
```

to

```
var getObjectResponse = client.GetObject(getObjectRequest);
```

where `client` is your S3 client.